# how should I add values to structures with partial arguments in solidity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

```
contract ClusterHeadNode {

  struct ClusterNode {
      
      string name;
      string[] ordinarynodes;
  }
  mapping(string => ClusterNode[]) clusternodes;

  
  mapping(string => string[]) headnodes;

  function addClusterNode(string memory  _basename , string memory _clustername) internal {
      
        clusternodes[_basename].push(ClusterNode(_clustername, null ));
        
    }
    
    function getClusterNodes(string memory _name) public view returns(string[] memory){
        return headnodes[_name];
    }

}
```

in the above code, i should add the only name in clusterNode structure

while trying this I'm getting an error

****contracts/hybridblockchain.sol:19:38: TypeError: Wrong argument count for struct constructor: 1 arguments given but expected 2. clusternodes[_basename].push(ClusterNode(_clustername ));**

please get me out of this or is they any alternative solution for this please let know

Answer (score 0):

Your struct contains two types: `string` and `string[]` (array of strings).

When you're creating the instance, you're passing `ClusterNode(_clustername, null )`. But `null` is not a valid value in Solidity and the compiler ignores it (not because it's invalid, but because it's null).

**Solution: pass an empty array**

*I made a minified example of passing an empty array based on your original code:*

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract ClusterHeadNode {

  struct ClusterNode {
      string name;
      string[] ordinarynodes;
  }

  mapping(string => ClusterNode[]) clusternodes;

  function addClusterNode(string memory _basename, string memory _clustername) external {
      string[] memory ordinarynodes;  // instanciate empty array
      ClusterNode memory clusternode = ClusterNode(_clustername, ordinarynodes); // instanciate the struct, pass the empty array to the struct
      clusternodes[_basename].push(clusternode); // push the struct into the array of structs
  }

}
```

Comment: when i try this code I'm getting this error **UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct ClusterNode memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.**

Comment: @vijaykumar The error is produced by something else than said code. Maybe you're incorrectly changing it? I was able to successfully compile (under Solidity 0.8.3) and create a transaction calling the `addClusterNode()` function. https://imgur.com/JQMQ7sK